# What are the conventions for indicating programming variables within text?

Tags: formatting

From my thesis:

> In this method, the **get_config_value** function is used that is defined within the PyWPS API.

How should I format the "**get_config_value**" variable?

It should be formatted differently than the rest of the text, but I don't know what the conventions are.  Using italic or bold fonts doesn't look right to me.

Comment: Do you mean that `get_config_value` is that variable?

Comment: yes. i should have used another sentence as an example. here it is not a variable as such, but a name of a function. still, i feel it should be formatted differently then the rest of the text.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is common to typeset code with a monospaced font (a font whose characters have all the same width), like `get_config_value`.

If you're using LaTeX to write your thesis, you can use the command `\texttt` for inline code. For clarity and flexibility, it's probably better to define a new command, e.g. `\newcommand{\code}[1]{\texttt{#1}}`. You can use the `listings` package for longer pieces of code.

For other typesetting systems or word processors, check their manual.