# What is the advantage of m·s^(-1) over m/s?

Tags: journals, mathematics, writing-style

It's everywhere, but no matter who I ask I can never get a straight answer, only "I don't know"s. What is the advantage of using multiplication and negative powers over just using division when writing out units, as in the question title. Granted, in most cases they use superscript rather than how I formatted it in the title, but my phone keyboard would not let me do that.

I don't have a problem reading units written this way, but it just seems inefficient as it uses more characters and makes it more difficult for "regular people" to follow. I'm suspecting it's nothing more than a style choice, possibly because it looks "more scientific".

Comment: I'm voting to close as off-topic. This isn't a question about academia: it's a question about one of the subjects that academics study.

Comment: @DavidRicherby This is just a question about writing style, exactly as we have questions about [styling code](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/139874/20058) or citations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally speaking, the choice of one form over another is better done on a case-by-case basis, according to readability.

If I have to specify a speed of 5 meters per second, I'll write *v* = 5 m/s rather than *v* = 5 m·s<sup>-1</sup>, because for most people the first form is more readable than the latter.

However, if I have to label the axis of a quantity with some complex unit, I may choose the form with the exponents. For, instance, if I have to report the spectral density function *S<sub>v</sub>(f)* of some voltage noise, whose unit is V<sup>2</sup>/Hz, I may label the vertical axis (according to the style [I described here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/28918/20058)) either

*S<sub>v</sub>(f)*/(V<sup>2</sup>/Hz) (with parentheses to avoid any ambiguity)

or

*S<sub>v</sub>(f)*/V<sup>2</sup>Hz<sup>-1</sup> (for compactness).

In this case, I'd probably choose the second form because is probably more readable even in the case of more complex units. Strictly speaking, also this second form without parentheses is ambiguous because multiplication and division are associative from left to right, but frequently people understand that unit as a single block.

*Remark.* If you use LaTeX to write papers I cannot but recommend to use the package `siunitx` to typeset the units, because it allows you to switch between the two forms with just one option (`per-mode=symbol` or `per-mode=reciprocal`). Moreover, it automatically adds a small space between the units.

Comment: Has anyone ever asked you "wait, what are $H$ and $z^{-1}$?"?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni He he... no. In any case, I write my papers in LaTeX and the `siunitx` package adds automatically a small spaces between each unit, and there's no risk of confusion.

Comment: Hold up, isn't $Hz^{-1}$ just $s$? Because isn't a Hz simply 1/s?

Comment: @vikarjramun Yes it is, but certain units are commonly written in certain preferred, more recognizable ways.

Comment: You can't write "5 ms^-1" because "ms" means millisecond. You would have to write "5 m·s^-1" instead.

Comment: @Nayuki Unfortunately there's no way here to render the small space, but using the dot between units is generally discouraged. See also my comment above to Federico.

Comment: Who said middle dot is discouraged? I see documents like this and it seems fine. https://physics.nist.gov/cuu/Units/checklist.html

Comment: @Nayuki I would not rate that source as they say "That dog weighs 10 kg" ... kg is a unit of mass not weight...

Comment: @Nayuki You're right, in principle they're both correct, also the SI brochure concurs. I amended the writing. In practice, however, metrologists usually avoid the dot.

Comment: There is a better way (in my opinion) to write the complex example in your answer in a correct and unambiguous way without parentheses: S_v(f) • Hz V^-2

Comment: @Alexander That's true, but when you write a paper you have to keep in mind the target audience and what's easily readable for them, not only the correctness.

Comment: @Massimo Ortolano: I disagree, only *correct* and *unambiguous* information can be understood the right way, especially if it gets complicated.

Comment: @Alexander You can disagree, but my experience is that sometimes it is better to present the information in a certain way rather than sticking to correctness at all cost. For instance, a common example is that of circuit diagrams: sometimes it is better to avoid certain IEC symbols in favour of more easily interpretable ones, albeit non standard.

Answer (score 24):

I think the main advantage is that an ambiguity of *a/bc* is avoided. For example, *g/m^2s* may be read as *g m^{-2} s^{-1}* or *g m^{-2} s* depending on whether multiplication takes priority over division.  As far as I know, there is no consistency in opinions about it, so to avoid confusion a slightly uglier notation with negative powers may be worth accepting.

Comment: Though in programming, the pretty much universal convention is _a_ / _b_ * _c_ ≡ (_a_ / _b_) * _c_. This is exactly analogous to _a_ − _b_ + _c_ ≡ (_a_ − _b_) + _c_. But of course, these language don't allow writing _b_ * _c_ as _b_ _c_ (let alone _bc_).

Comment: In that case you can write $gs/m^2$ or $g/m^2/s$.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I agree about conventions in programming, however, my maths students often miscode $\frac{a}{b c}$ as a/b*c which makes me think they've used to a different convention somewhere.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: but few will say that 1/2pi is equal to pi/2.

Comment: But, if you're attempting to eliminate ambiguity, then *a/bc* can be trivially written as *a/(bc)*, or *g/(m^2s)* as in your example, which adds two characters to the representation, whereas *g m^{-2} s^{-1}* and *g m^{-2} s* adds 7 characters and 3 characters respectively (not counting the space characters added to your examples). Arguably, those also remove the ambiguity between interpreting the original as *g/((m^2)s)* and *g/(m^(2s))*, but that could be resolved by writing it as *g/(sm^2)*.

Comment: +1 because avoiding ambiguity/ensuring correctness is indeed the main reason. I would add that especially for more complicated units, using parentheses or fraction bars is not very practical especially when integrated into a text or into an axis label in a plot. In order to keep things consistent, the way of writing units with negative exponents is then also used for rather simple units like the one in the question. And for me, it is also better in terms of readability.

Comment: @MartinArgerami When reading your comment, I read 1/2pi as "one half pi", soooo...

Comment: @OldBunny2800: I said "few", not "none".

Answer (score 1):

Personal preference, but having the numbers be explicit helps me with checking the dimensions of the final answer (it's easier to see which terms cancel, especially if the exponents are non integers as I don't need to keep subtracting 1 as 1/x^0.5 is actually x^-0.5)

Answer (score 1):

Dimitry's answer is probably the most complete, but for me, the issue is around ambiguity in fractions.  For example I would never write `a/bc`, because it is ambiguous, I would right (in LaTeX) `\frac{a}{bc}` or `ab^{-1}c^{-1}`.  The former I find much neater for an equation out in the open, while the later looks a bit better if included in-line text.

Answer (score 1):

Another significant advantage of using negative powers to me is that checking for correctness of units becomes easier. In physics especially, any physically meaningful formula or identity should have units which match up on both sides, so if the units not match up for an equation, this can be an effective check that the equation can't possibly be correct. This is a common way to check one's work, and can even be taken further: see [Dimensional Analysis](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensional_analysis).

Now, working with units is much easier with negative exponents. Consider the equation distance = velocity × time. The (SI) units of the LHS are (m), that of velocity is (m/s), and that of time is (s). It is easier to see that m·s^(-1)s=m than that (m/s)s=m to many people. Of course the difference is slight because the formula is simple in this case, but once one starts working with more complicated equations dimensional analysis becomes much easier once you abandon the forward slash notation.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps its not an academic reason, but more of a practical reason combined with tradition/preference for the earlier format learned?

Historically, typesetters may not have been able to render what is now easy with various markup notations.

39.3396 m/s might be accidentally read as "mis" or "mls" or "mi5"  where (m.s^-1) is unambiguous.

---

A horizontal fraction bar will also break up the flow of a paragraph of printed text, so this presentation keeps the units to be one "line of text" high.

---

"m/s"  when sent by morse code is

```
   --     -..-.    ...
```

Since the forward slash is a relatively rare character, could be accidentally transcribed as one of these:

```
   --     -..     -.    ...
    m      d      n      s

   --     -.     .-.    ...
    m      n      r      s

   --     -   ..   -   .    ...
    m    you get the idea...
```

---

```
  $39.3396 \frac{m}{s}$
```

should render unambiguously like this   (if mathtex were supported here)

[image]